# Install D-Link DWA-140 B1 drivers

Tags: drivers, wireless, d-link

I am new to ubuntu so I have no experience with it. I have installed the latest version of ubuntu but now I need to install drivers (I think) for my DWA-140 B1 wifi dongle. From what I've read there is a default driver (rt2800usb) which I think will work. When I look at the D-Link support page there are drivers for it but they haven't been updated since 2010. Should I use the default drivers or the factory drivers? If I use the factory drivers how do you install them? If I use the default drivers how do I configure the drive?

Comment: I suggest that you stick the device in the USB slot and check to see if a driver loaded: `lsmod | grep rt2` Then click the Network Manager icon and see if you see your network and connect.

Comment: As far I known it should work out-the-box. Ralink is linux-friendly.

Comment: I probably should have just plugged it in... works without doing anything. I’m really liking this system, fast and doesn’t have any of the annoying windows stuff.